# black screen manager kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to build a simple Kivy (1.10.1) App with a screen manager and .kv files, but I keep getting a black screen.

My ScreenManager (GUI/nco.py)

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from GUI.login import LoginScreen

class NCO(ScreenManager):
    def add_widget(self, screen):
        super(NCO, self).add_widget(screen)
        # TODO: add a radial gradiant background from (0, 155, 190) to (0, 5, 20)
        print("added screen:", screen.name)

class NCOApp(App):
    def build(self):
        nco = NCO()
        nco.add_widget(LoginScreen(name="login"))
        return nco
```

GUI/login.py

```py
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def test(self):
        mail = self.ids.mail.text.strip()
        pwd = self.ids.pwd.text
        print("e-mail:", mail)
        print("password:", pwd)
```

GUI/login.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.1

<LoginScreen>:
    AnchorLayout:
        size: self.parent.size

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: None, None
            size: 400, 35
            orientation: "horizontal"

            TextInput:
                id: mail
                font_size: 20
                hint_text: "e-mail"
                multiline: False
                write_tab: False

            TextInput:
                id: pwd
                font_size: 20
                password: True
                hint_text: "password"
                multiline: False
                write_tab: False

            Button:
                size_hint: .3, 1
                text: "login"
                on_press: root.manager.current.test()
```

main.py

```py
from GUI.nco import NCOApp
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set("graphics", "fullscreen", "auto")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NCOApp().run()
```

I already succeeded at displaying the login screen when I wasn't using a ScreenManager, and it worked without calling `Builder.load_string()`
I've searched online and every working solutions involve calling `Builder.load_string()` which I would prefer not to use, is it possible to make it work ?

Comment: A video I've made on this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU8jjgzH1LE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem - Black Window

1) When main.py is executed, Kivy looks for a Kv file with the same name as your App class in lowercase, minus “App” if it ends with ‘App’ e.g:

```
NCOApp -> nco.kv
```

2) You have created instances of LoginScreen but there is no view associated with it.

## Solution

Create a kv file, nco.kv in folder GUI and add the following view for LoginScreen:

```
#:include GUI//login.kv
```

## Output

[image: Kivy Output]

Comment: thanks for the explanation i'm trying this right now :D
I'll tell you how it goes

Comment: thanks, it worked! I unfortunately can't upvote cause not enough rep but I validated the answer